# How to disallow Chrome Prerendering?

Tags: php, google-chrome, caching, session-variables

As a user you can Edit Google Chrome's Prerendering setting by:

1. Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings > click Show advanced settings.
3. In the "Privacy" section, use the "**Predict network actions to improve page load performance**" checkbox to enable or disable the feature.

If the user chooses to enable this (or enabled by default).

How can I force Google Chrome NOT to prefetch pages in my website?

This is creating serious issues with my `$_SESSIONS`, ie:

- User logs out and is taken to a "prefecthed/prerendered" page where he is logged in
- User accesses a page which requires login credentials, and not have access because this page was "prefecthed/prerendered" when he was logged out (and session was unset)

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

I found if you add this javascript:

```
<script>
if (document.webkitVisibilityState == 'prerender' ||  document.visibilityState ==    'prerender' || document.visibilityState[0] == 'prerender') {
  alert('no thanks google');
} 
</script>
```

The document doesnt get prerendered as the Status of: `Javascript Alert` is returned in the chrome://net-internals/#prerender console.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You should have code on this page that says if they are not logged in redirect them to login.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33415/is-it-possible-to-stop-chrome-and-other-browsers-from-pre-fetching-rendering-my

Comment: I have, but the user IS Logged in when he does this, but the paged has been prerendered while the user was logged out. I just need to know how to avoid Chrome from doing this.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Tried to modify the .htaccess as suggested but didnt work

Comment: there may be some error in your code, this option is on by default and I have not experienced them problem you describe, please post the code that checks if the user is logged in.

Comment: trust me @Pwner, this is the issue. I check if a user is online by checking the `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {`, this isnt the problem. Issue only exists when pages have been prerendered as seen in chrome://net-internals/#prerender

Comment: IE(11) has a similar option: Load sites and content in the background to optimize performance.  This is also on by default, do you get the same problem there?

Comment: Also code above checks if they ARE logged in, what is executed if they ARE NOT logged in.

Comment: @Pwner please stay ontopic. There is no log in problems. A I mentioned this issue ONLY occurs when the page is being prerenred by google which is not 100% of the time. With this option disabled it works fine, as it does on my Localhost. Regarding IE(11), I can't appreciate the same issue as with Google Chrome.